# If value exists in one table check a value exists at same relative reference in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im not sure what i would like to do is even possible in one formula but I thought it was worth asking the question.

I have 2 tables of information, a simplified version is shown in the image below:

[image: Data Tables]

What I would like to do is have a formula in cell A3, A4 and A5 which checks for values in those rows. If a value exists it checks values also exist in the corresponding row in the second table in the same columns as the first table.

The example shows the result i would like to achieve. Rows A3 and A4 are correct but a value is missing from the second table in cell G11 so the formula should identify row A5 as having an error.

Hope this makes sense. If you need more info let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in A3 and drag down as fas as needed:

```
=IF(PRODUCT(--((C3:H3<>"")=(C8:H8<>""))),"Yes","No")
```

Please Note, that this is an **Array Formula**. When you put this formula in A2, you don't ommit it like usual, with pressing `Enter` but you have to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

Comment: Perfect thanks - looks very simple now I've seen it!